# Switch from UINavigationController to UISplitviewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` presenting a couple of `UIViewControllers`. Then I want to switch to a `UISplitviewController`.

So I implemented a method `useSplitViewController` in my app-Delegate that I call from my last `UIViewController`. It shows the `SplitView`, but I can't rotate my device. The `ViewController`s inside my `SplitviewController` don't get the rotation-event. What is my mistake and how can I solve it?

```
 -(void)useSplitViewController{

    [self.menuViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.menuViewController = nil;
    self.navcon = nil;

    self.splitViewController =[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
    self.rootViewController=[[RootViewController alloc]init];
    self.detailViewController=[[[FirstDetailViewController alloc]init] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *rootNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    UINavigationController *detailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];


    self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailNav,nil];
    self.splitViewController.delegate=self.detailViewController;

    // Add the split view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


    self.navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
    self.menuViewController.appDelegate = self;
    [self.navcon pushViewController:self.menuViewController animated:NO];


    [window addSubview:self.menuViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //[self useSplitViewController];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the root view controller of the window:

replace

```
[window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
```

with,

```
[window setRootViewController:self.splitViewController];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to to the same with the UINavigationViewController and than it worked!